# YubiHSM 2 PKCS11 Cant connect

Tags: security, openssl, pkcs#11, hsm, yubico

I have a YubiHSM2 HSM device and want to access it via PKCS11. I have installed the YubiHSM2 drivers as well as Libp11 and OpenSC tools.

However, when I try to connect and generate a key via:

```
pkcs11-tool --module 'C:\Users\myUser\yubihsm2-sdk\bin\yubihsm_pkcs11.dll --login --pin 0001password \
    --keypairgen --key-type rsa:2048 --label "my_key" --usage-sign
```

I receive:

```
error: Failed to laod pkcs11 module
Aborting.
```

I am thinking maybe I am adressing the dll file wrong? I am trying to implement this on Windows, I had it working on Unix System where I had to address a xxx.so file.

Does anyone have an idea or similar experience with a HSM module?
Thanks for your help!
Best regards
LikeAKemper

Comment: for more information see: https://developers.yubico.com/YubiHSM2/Usage_Guides/OpenSSL_with_pkcs11_engine.html

Comment: is the unmatched`'` a typo?

Comment: yes that's a typo. any information regarding correctly addressing/loading a dll file would be really helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

@everyone.
I found the issue. It only works if I am already in the directory where the DLL is located. Now I am not sure why this is an issue for the command so let me know if you something about that.
Anyway thank you.

Comment: My guess is that `yubihsm_pkcs11.dll` depends on other libraries present in `C:\Users\myUser\yubihsm2-sdk\bin` dir. You can set that dir as a current dir (your solution) or you can add that dir to `PATH` environment variable.